# In R: How to apply a function to a column given the value of another column

Tags: r, na

I have a dataframe with 1s and NAs. I would like to replace the NAs with zeros but not if the entire row is NA as this would indicate a true NA.

For example, here is a simplified data frame:

```
A<-c(NA,NA,1,1)
B<-c(NA,NA,NA,1)
C<-c(1,NA,NA,NA)
df<-data.frame(A,B,C)
df$D<-ifelse(!is.na(df$A) | !is.na(df$B) | !is.na(df$C), 1,0)

A   B   C  
NA  NA  1  
NA  NA  NA  
1   NA  NA  
1   1   NA
```

Columns A B and C have either 1s or blanks (NA). I would like to replace the blanks with zeros (0), but NOT when A, B, and C are all blank. I have created column D as an indicator of whether or not there is any data in A B C. Now I need a code to replace NA with zero. I hope this makes sense.

I am hoping the output will look like this:

```
A B C  D
0 0 1  1
       0
1 0 0  1
1 1 0  1
```

I used the following code to produce column D

```
df$D<-ifelse(!is.na(df$A) | !is.na(df$B) | !is.na(df$C), 1,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach based on the result of a `rowSums` (with hint from @Ritchie Sacramento)

```
replace(df, rowSums(df, na.rm = T) > 0 & is.na(df), 0)
   A  B  C
1  0  0  1
2 NA NA NA
3  1  0  0
4  1  1  0
```

Comment: Forgive me, I am very new to this. If columns A:C were part of a larger dataframe, how would I subset/specify the columns for this line of code to be applied to?

Comment: @dev You can subset the larger df by column name like this `replace(df[,c("A","B","C")], rowSums(df[,c("A","B","C")], na.rm = T) > 0 & is.na(df[,c("A","B","C")]), 0)`

Comment: @dev ... or simply by position, e.g. `df[,1:3]`

Comment: @dev for convenience and clarity you can also store the column names in a variable and use it as index, e.g. `Sub <- c("A","B","C"); df[,Sub]`

Comment: Thank you! I have got the right output now. I am hoping to have the original dataframe modified as well though. Right now I get a printout but the dataframe remains original with NAs instead of zeros

Comment: @dev reassign it. Using the `Sub` variable it looks something like this `df[,Sub] <- replace(df[,Sub], rowSums(df[,Sub], na.rm = T) > 0 & is.na(df[,Sub]), 0)`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to capture the rows that are all `NA`, replace all the `NA` with zero, and then go back and re-populate the `NA`:

```r
all_na <- apply(is.na(df), 1, all)
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df[all_na,] <- NA
```

Otherwise you can try it like this:

```r
data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, \(x) if (all(is.na(x))) x else replace(x, is.na(x), 0))))
#    A  B  C
# 1  0  0  1
# 2 NA NA NA
# 3  1  0  0
# 4  1  1  0
```

Comment: Would the first option work? How would it know it was all NA if I had replaced them with zeros?

Comment: You capture that information before the replacement. That's what `all_na` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Sample DataFrame
df <- data.frame(A = c(NA, NA, 1, 1),
                 B = c(NA, NA, NA, 1),
                 C = c(1, NA, NA, NA))

# Create column D
df$D <- ifelse(!is.na(df$A) | !is.na(df$B) | !is.na(df$C), 1, 0)

# Replace NAs with zeros in columns A, B, and C, based on column D
df[df$D == 1, c("A", "B", "C")] <- lapply(df[df$D == 1, c("A", "B", "C")], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))

# Print the modified DataFrame
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for a `rowwise()` operation with `dplyr`. We can include the complex logical statement inside `replace()`.
This is a nice approach because `dplyr` allows good flexibility for applying the method to different subsets of data.

#### Answer if the index column D already exists:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
    rowwise() |> 
    mutate(across(A:C, \(x) replace(x, is.na(x) & D, 0))) |>
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 × 4
      A     B     C     D
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     1     1
2    NA    NA    NA     0
3     1     0     0     1
```

#### We can also create the index on-the-fly, with `dplyr::if_all`:

```
df |> 
    rowwise() |> 
    mutate(across(A:C, \(x) replace(x, is.na(x) & !if_all(A:C, is.na), 0))) |>
    ungroup()
```